# Eclipse 32 bit with Java 32 bit on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, java

I'm having a hard time getting Eclipse 3.5 SR2 (helios) to run on my Windows 7 x64 machine.

I am running 32 bit version of Eclipse, and 32 bit version o Java.  I have created JAVA_HOME and I have pointed it to "C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_25".  I have added %JAVA_HOME%\bin; to the beginning of my Path variable.

When I launch Eclipse I get a error message stating that JRE and JDK are not in my current path and it can't fine javaw.exe.  But it state "No JVM was found after searching the following locations: D:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse_3.5.SR2\jre\bin\javaw.exe".

The path is the Eclipse path with "jre\bin" thrown on the end.  Tomcat doesn't have a problem finding where the JRE/JDK are.  I'm guessing it's pulling it out of the registy.

If I put the following in Eclipse.ini Eclipse will launch file

-vm 
C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.6.0_25

But the problem with this, is I have a custom DLL that is running in Tomcat\bin, and I can now no longer run tomcat inside of Eclipse because it doesn't seem to be picking up the proper path.

My question is, how do I get Eclipse to use the Path env variable.  I want to use that to get the proper java, as well as it includes the path to my custom dll.

Comment: Did you try setting the full path of the vm in the eclipse.ini (including its spaces)?

Comment: Have you checked for conflicts in other locations on PATH ? Java files sometimes ends up windows/system32 which might confuse eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` directory to see if there is `java.exe` and `javaw.exe` there. If they are there, try to add the directory to your PATH env variable.